# NSFetchedResultsController / NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate double/triple/… sections on insert

Tags: ios, core-data

I have a (at least for me) strang problem here:

I have the have an UITableViewController which has a NSFetchedResultsController to handle the data to display.

The data that should be displayed comes from a server and to make it easier, lets say it's kind of a chat.

A simplified model could be described as follows.

```
---------------           -----------------           -----------------
|  MainTopic  |           |     Thread    |           |    Message    |
---------------           -----------------           -----------------
| topicID (E) |           | threadID (E)  |           |   msgID   (E) |
| name (E)    |           | name (E)      |           |   msgText (E) |
---------------           -----------------           |   msgDate (E) |           
| threads (R) | <------>> | mainTopic (R) |           -----------------
---------------           | messages (R)  | <------>> |   thread (R)  |
                          -----------------           -----------------
```

The data comes from a server which populates always ALL messages for a MainTopic (this is not in my hand).

For CoreData I have a Controller which is implemented as singleton. It has a mainContext (NSManagedObjectContext) which is used by the NSFetchedResultsController. Inserting new data is done on a separate NSManagedObjectContext which calls mergeChangesFromContextDidSaveNotification: on the mainContext when it is saved.

The Thread class has a compare:-Method so it can also be used for the sortdescriptor.

Back to the UITableViewController:

On viewDidLoad it creates the NSFetchedResultsController which gets all the messages for a topicID and the sectionNameKeyPath is set to "thread" and performs a fetch on the FetchedResultsController.

The UITableView also implements NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate so that the TableView gets updated if new messages arrive. And this is where my problem starts.

After a fresh fetch from the server the Table View could look as follows

```
______________________________________
| Thread: First thread               |
|____________________________________|
|____________________________________|
| Message 1                          |
| Message 2                          |
|____________________________________|
| Thread: Second thread              |
|____________________________________|
|____________________________________|
| Message 1                          |
| Message 2                          |
|____________________________________|
```

Now someone writes a message (Message 3) into the first thread, the data is fetched from the server (user remains in the table view). Now the table view looks like this

```
______________________________________
| Thread: First thread               |
|____________________________________|
|____________________________________|
| Message 1                          |
| Message 2                          |
|____________________________________|
| Thread: First thread               |
|____________________________________|
|____________________________________|
| Message 3                          |
|____________________________________|
| Thread: Second thread              |
|____________________________________|
|____________________________________|
| Message 1                          |
| Message 2                          |
|____________________________________|
```

As you can see, the section header for the first thread appears twice.

If the UITableViewController will be left and opened up again (poped and new instance pushed to the navigationController) the table looks fine:

```
______________________________________
| Thread: First thread               |
|____________________________________|
|____________________________________|
| Message 1                          |
| Message 2                          |
| Message 3                          |
|____________________________________|
| Thread: Second thread              |
|____________________________________|
|____________________________________|
| Message 1                          |
| Message 2                          |
|____________________________________|
```

So I think that the error must be somewhere in the NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate methods, but for they look "normal".

```
#pragma mark - NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate methods

- (void)controllerWillChangeContent:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller
{
    [[self tableView] beginUpdates];
}

- (void)controller:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller
  didChangeSection:(id<NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo>)sectionInfo
           atIndex:(NSUInteger)sectionIndex
     forChangeType:(NSFetchedResultsChangeType)type
{

    NSIndexSet * indexSet = [NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:sectionIndex];
    switch (type) {
        case NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert:
            [[self tableView] insertSections:indexSet
                            withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;

        case NSFetchedResultsChangeDelete:
            [[self tableView] deleteSections:indexSet
                            withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}

- (void)controller:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller
   didChangeObject:(id)anObject
       atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
     forChangeType:(NSFetchedResultsChangeType)type
      newIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)newIndexPath
{
    NSArray * oldArray = nil;
    if(indexPath) {
        oldArray = [NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath];
    }
    NSArray * newArray = nil;
    if(newIndexPath) {
        newArray = [NSArray arrayWithObject:newIndexPath];
    }

    switch(type) {
        case NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert:
            [[self tableView] insertRowsAtIndexPaths:newArray
                                    withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;
        case NSFetchedResultsChangeDelete:
            [[self tableView] deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:oldArray
                                    withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;
        case NSFetchedResultsChangeUpdate:
        {
            UITableViewCell * cell = nil;
            Message * message = nil;
            cell = [[self tableView] cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
            message = [[self fetchedResultsController] objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];

            [cell setMessageText:[message msgText]];
        }
            break;
        case NSFetchedResultsChangeMove:
            [[self tableView] insertRowsAtIndexPaths:newArray
                                    withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];

            [[self tableView] deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:oldArray
                                    withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];

            break;
    }
}


- (void)controllerDidChangeContent:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller
{
    [[self tableView] endUpdates];
}
```

So, does someone has a hint for me, where the problem could be?

Comment: Can you show your code which creates the fetched results controller?

Comment: I don't think the error is in the frc delegate methods. If the "didChangeSection:" method gets called the table is just doing what it's been told to do (i.e., add a section). "didChangeSection:" is called because the controller "believes" that a new section is being added so it seems to me your problem is somewhere else. When you figure it out, let us know what the problem was.